# CTE goes in infinite loop?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, recursive-query, sql-function

I have a table structure like this

[image]

Where I want to recur till `if(text_id = new_text_id)`.
So suppose I pass 1 as `text_id` I want in return `5` as `text_id` using CTE.

I tried but it goes in infinite loop, tried maxrecursion still

```
WITH textHierarchy AS (
    SELECT tm.text_id
    FROM text_master tm 
    WHERE tm.text_id = 1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT tm.text_id
    FROM text_master as tm
    JOIN textHierarchy AS txtHr ON tm.text_id = txtHr.new_text_id -- Terminating Condition
    WHERE txtHr.new_text_id IS NOT NULL 

)
SELECT * FROM textHierarchy option (maxrecursion 5);
```

Please tell me what I am doing wrong.

My aim is to use this CTE inside a database function and call that function from Java.

And can a CTE be used inside a function. If so how?

Comment: If `new_text_id` for row 5 was null rather than 5, it looks like it should work fine. Confusion between what you want the terminating condition to be?

Comment: I want it to recursively iterate till text_id = new_text_id is not found. And include last result i:e If I pass 1 as text_id then return all 5 results. And If I pass 4 as text_id then return only last 2 records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
create table dbo.text_master_test
(
text_id int,
text_details nvarchar(max),
new_text_id int
)
go

insert into text_master_test
values(1, 'det 1',2), (2, 'det 2',3), (3, 'det 3',4), (4, 'det 4',5), (5, 'det 5',5);
go


WITH textHierarchy AS (
    SELECT tm.text_id, tm.new_text_id, nullif(tm.new_text_id, tm.text_id) as next_text_id
    FROM text_master_test tm 
    WHERE tm.text_id = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT tm.text_id, tm.new_text_id, nullif(tm.new_text_id, tm.text_id) as next_text_id
    FROM text_master_test as tm
    JOIN textHierarchy AS txtHr ON tm.text_id = txtHr.next_text_id 

)
SELECT * FROM textHierarchy;
go


create function dbo.textrecursion(@start_text_id int)
returns table
as
return
(
WITH textHierarchy 
AS 
(
    SELECT tm.text_id, tm.text_details, tm.new_text_id, 
        nullif(tm.new_text_id, tm.text_id) as next_text_id
    FROM dbo.text_master_test tm 
    WHERE tm.text_id = @start_text_id
    UNION ALL
    SELECT tm.text_id, tm.text_details, tm.new_text_id,
        nullif(tm.new_text_id, tm.text_id) as next_text_id
    FROM dbo.text_master_test as tm
    JOIN textHierarchy AS txtHr ON tm.text_id = txtHr.next_text_id 
)
select text_id, text_details, new_text_id
from textHierarchy
);
go

select *
from dbo.textrecursion(1)

select *
from dbo.textrecursion(4)

select *
from dbo.textrecursion(5)
go

drop function dbo.textrecursion;
go
drop table dbo.text_master_test
go
```

Comment: Thanks! it worked great.  One question why have you used nullif(tm.new_text_id, tm.text_id). Can the CTE doesn't work without it

Comment: you can completely ignore the nullif part&next_text_id column in the cte and use the `WHERE txtHr.text_id <> txtHr.new_text_id -- Termination condition`  in the answer by  GMB..,there is a tiny difference of how the cte is executed but not that important.

Answer (score 0):

What you commented as a termination condition is not that. That's a joining condition that defines the relation between the current iteration and the next one.

I think that you want:

```
WITH textHierarchy AS (
    SELECT tm.text_id
    FROM text_master tm 
    WHERE tm.text_id = 1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT tm.text_id
    FROM text_master as tm
    JOIN textHierarchy AS txtHr ON tm.text_id = txtHr.new_text_id 
    WHERE txtHr.text_id <> txtHr.new_text_id -- Termination condition

)
SELECT * FROM textHierarchy option (maxrecursion 5);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this below query. I passed text_id=1

```
;WITH Numbers(text_id) AS
(
    SELECT text_id
    from rectab
    where text_id=1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT text_id
    FROM rectab
    WHERE text_id=new_text_id
)
SELECT text_id
FROM Numbers;
```

Comment: It did not work as it only gives output where text_id = new_text_id. But I need all data. But thanks for trying. The above mentioned solution by @Iptr worked for me please look at that.